# javascript regex help

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to validate if a certain company was already picked for an application. the companyList format is:

> 60,261,420  ( a list of companyID)

I used

```
cID = $('#coName').val().split('::')[1];
```

to get the id only.

I am calling this function by passing say 60:

```
    findCompany = function(value) {
    var v = /^.+60,261,420$/.test(value);
    alert(v);   
}
```

when I pass the exact same string, i get false. any help?

Comment: What is "#companyList#" here?  In other words, what does that regex look like when you do a view source on the page?

Comment: what is cfoutput tag for? Can you see what is the javascript in your browser, not in the source code. The tag will be substituted with something.

Comment: @Romario I'm guessing it's a ColdFusion thing.

Comment: sorry, yes it is in coldfusion

Comment: @Pointy, i edited my post to include what is in view source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your company list is a list of numeric IDs like that, you need to make the resulting regular expression actually be the *correct* expression — if that's even the way you want to do it.

Another option is to just make an array, and then test for the value being in the array.

As a regex, though, what you could do is this:

```
var companyList = [<cfoutput> whatever </cfoutput>]; // get company ID list as an array of numbers
var companyRegex = new RegExp("^(?:" + companyList.join('|') + ")$");
```

Then you can say:

```
function findCompany(id) {
  if (companyRegex.test(id)) alert(id + " is already in the list!");
}
```

Comment: sweet! companyRegex.text(id) should read companyRegex.test(id)

Comment: Also, note that as soon as you start getting a serious number of companies, this is going to get a little weird. It should work fine however up to a few hundred I guess. Make sure you try it with a big list of ids just so you know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Why not split the string into an array, like you did for your testing, iterate over the list and check if it's in?

A regexp just for that is balls, overhead and slower. A lot.

Anyway, for your specific question:

You’re checking the string `"60"` for `/^.+60,261,420$/`.

.+60 will obviously not match because you require at least one character before the 60. The commas also evaluate and are not in your String.

I don’t quite get where your regexp comes from.

Were you looking for a regexp to OR them a hard-coded list of IDs?

Code for splitting it and checking the array of IDs:

```
findCompany = function(value) {
  $('#coName').val().split('::').each(function(val){
    if(val == value) return true;
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i am looking for a regexp. i tried to create one but it's not right obviously. the ids come from a query, then i convert to a list. i will give it a try for the array search

Comment: `$` <- is that jQuery? Within your check-fn: `$('#coName').val().split('::').each(function(val){ if(val == value) return true; }); return false;`.

Comment: Ok, it’s not jQuery. What lib is it? It probably also has some each function? If not you’ll have to use JavaScripts `for(var val in coNameText)`.